# Citation not working

Tags: biblatex

In my `.bib` file I have two entries as follows:

```
@book{si20,
    title = {Introduction to Econometrics with R},
    author = {Schmelzer, Martin Arnold, Alexander Gerber, and Martin, Christoph Hanck},
    url = {https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/},
    urldate = {2020-10-02},
    year = {2020}
}

@Article{pcalg,
    title = {Causal Inference Using Graphical Models with the {R}
      Package {pcalg}},
    author = {Markus Kalisch and Martin M\"achler and Diego Colombo and
      Marloes H. Maathuis and Peter B\"uhlmann},
    journal = {Journal of Statistical Software},
    year = {2012},
    volume = {47},
    number = {11},
    pages = {1--26},
    url = {https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v047i11},
  }
```

My  document looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Test citations}
\author{Jaime Sevilla}
\date{November 2020}
\usepackage[
backend=biber, natbib,
style=numeric
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{name.bib}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\cite{si20}

\cite{pcalg}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

At first sight I would think that both `bib` entries are correctly formatted. But only the second one works!

[image: PDF output]

What is going on? How do I fix the first `bib` entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the author field in the `si20` entry is missing some "and"s to separate the authors. The correct formatting for `si20` should look something like this:

```
@book{si20,
    title = {Introduction to Econometrics with R},
    author = {Hanck, Christoph and Arnold, Martin and Gerber, Alexander and Schmelzer, Martin},
    url = {https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/},
    urldate = {2020-10-02},
    year = {2020}
}
```